# Team Services Release Management backup before deployment

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm wondering if there was a way in Team Services for a release definition to have a step that backs up the directory for the application before it deploys the updated code.

I currently do a manual process before we deploy an update of an application where I take the application directory and back it up to a compressed file with the name containing the date of the deployment in the file name, which we do to satisfy our requirements for backups to our Change Control Board.  I would like to make this automated process so that it's done the same way each time, even if I'm not the one over the deployment.  I know you can do command line tasks and I could write a command line application that takes certain parameters but would like to know if Team Services may already have a task in place that can take care of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a Copy Files and a Zip Files task which you can drop into your process. You can even make the tasks conditional. There isn't a "backup" task per-se.

However, there is no "rollback" task, the normal thing to do would be to schedule a new release with the previous version to install. Or to fix the issue and trigger a new release with the fixed contents.

Comment: So, I actually wrote powershell script that does all of this, plus timestamps the filename.